# QGIS 3.16 and 3.20 Georeferencer freeze issue

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, hardware

Has anyone across the geo-referencer freezing on 3.16 LRE and 3.20? I have tried this with multiple different jpegs and tiffs. The progress indication bar sticks on 0% and the only way to resolve this is to end the program ctrl/alt/del.

This was never a problem until a few weeks back when moved software onto a new workstation. I have not been able to resolve this with uninstalling/re-install.

This feels like a bug. Could this be related to hardware given it was working on the old workstation?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Please provide referencing settings, as well as insight into whether this happens for different images/settings/points/CRS.

Comment: I sometimes had similar experiences and then discovered a control point out of the image or on its corner (don't know how it got there). When deleting it, everything went smooth. So control if you don't have any unintended control points. Create a few new control points and try to run it like this.

Comment: @Ahujeffy Have you tried creating a new profile?

Comment: could you post your gdal script (in the georeferencer menu "generate gdal script")

Answer (score 3):

Yes I have - Same problem - solution below.

It was working fine on 3.16 but then didn't work on 3.18. Luckily I had kept 3.16 installed and found it still worked on that. 3.20 and 3.22 also gave me the same problem but the georeferencer in my 3.16 remaining working.

Unfortunately I removed all versions of QGIS yesterday and reinstalled just 3.22 to try and clean my system and see if it fixed things - which it didn't. And the same problem was then happening in 3.16 after reinstalling it in parallel with 3.22.

SOLUTION - what I finally found worked for me was creating a new user profile. Go to 'Settings' in the main QGIS menu bar, 'User profiles', 'New profile...'